With Hibernate Second Level Caching Enabled Select query fetching data from DataBase on every Request
I have three Entity Class MyEntity1,MyEntity2,MyEntity3. Each of this classes are marked with
@Cacheable(true).
Following Structure of MyEntity1 is as below
class MyEntity1{

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "myEntity1")
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
  private Set<MyEntity2> myEntities2;
  
  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy,mappedBy="myEntity1",cascade=CascadeType.All) 
  @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
  private MyEntity3 myEntity3;
}

Now the problem is MyEntity2 is getting cached properly but MyEntity3 is not getting cached in spite of being Marked with @Cacheable(true).
Definition of MyEntity3 is as below
  @Entity
  @Cacheable(true)
  @NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name="myQuery",query="...",@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")) 
 })
 Class MyEntity3{
//instance fields
 }

I am not able to figure out why MyEntity3 is not getting cached while other entities are getting cached?
Can anyone help in this?
